# How to add notes to a PowerPoint (officer)

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

I'm creating a PowerPoint document from R using the officer package and I'd like to add notes to my slides.

**Is it possible to add notes to a particular powerpoint slide from R (preferably using the officer package)?**

I'm really unsure if an appropriate function exists within the `officeR` (or any other) R package.

A workaround that I was thinking about was creating a custom slide layout (in the PowerPoint template file that I'm using) that contains the notes and then simply using this layout when I create the deck within R. But unfortunately it seems that PowerPoint doesn't let you add notes to a slide layout within the Master View.

Comment: dear Tom, this question is discussed here: https://github.com/davidgohel/officer/issues/90

Comment: @DavidGohel Thanks for your comment! Good to know that this indeed doesn't exist yet within officeR. I'm glad to see that this is already in the pipelline:-) I'm going to leave the question open for now, maybe someone has a suggestion for a workaround.

Comment: there is a workaround with rmarkdown, the new version is handling comments in powerpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Officer now has a [`set_notes` function](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/reference/set_notes.html) that allows you to add notes to a slide.

As David Gohel mentioned, notes are directly supported in [rmarkdown](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004672913-Rendering-PowerPoint-Presentations-with-the-RStudio-IDE#speaker-notes) and work with officedown ppt templates.

```
## My Slide

- Awesome
- Slide
- Content


::: notes
These are notes for ppt
:::
```